# JMX Metrics and New Relic

Tags: corda

We have new relic’s agent to our configuration to get exposure and understand the configuration and capture of JMX metrics.  Our CorDapp new shows up under our new relic account.  However, the only metrics being captured and displayed are general and related to the JVM.

The only source file including the @MXBean annotation is HibernateStatistics.

I see under master that there is more details around metrics and monitoring.

I assume that the additional metric capture did not happen until after V3.1.

I am just looking to confirm that we are not overlooking something and metrics should actually for flows and transactions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Corda 3.1, the only Corda-specific metrics exposed are:

- The number of attachments (`net.corda:name=Attachments`)
- The flow checkpointing rate (`net.corda:type=Flows,name=Checkpointing Rate`)
- The number of started flows (`net.corda:type=Flows,name=Started`)
- The number of in-flight flows (`net.corda:type=Flows,name=InFlight`)
- The number of finished flows (`net.corda:type=Flows,name=Finished`)

Apache Artemis metrics are also exposed. The list of exposed metrics can be found here: https://docs.corda.net/node-administration.html#monitoring-your-node. As you note, future versions of Corda will expand this list of metrics.

The flow metrics are registered when the node's `StateMachineManager` is instantiated in [`StateMachineManagerImpl.kt`](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V3/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/statemachine/StateMachineManagerImpl.kt), as follows:

```
// Monitoring support.
private val metrics = serviceHub.monitoringService.metrics

init {
    metrics.register("Flows.InFlight", Gauge<Int> { mutex.content.stateMachines.size })
}

private val checkpointingMeter = metrics.meter("Flows.Checkpointing Rate")
private val totalStartedFlows = metrics.counter("Flows.Started")
private val totalFinishedFlows = metrics.counter("Flows.Finished")
```

Comment: Hey @Joel, Thanks.  I saw the above documentation.   We are grasping at straws here, I thought maybe the reason we were not seeing corda specific metrics was because 'exportHibernateJMXStatistics" was not turned on.  But, after enabling, still not seeing metrics.  I've turned logging on new relic up to finest just to be sure.  But still no flow specific metrics.  Was going to join open office but being independence day here in the states, that did not happen.  Can you point out in the code where the 'flow' metrics are being added?   What are the metric names?

Comment: I've added metric names and where the flow metrics are registered in code.

Comment: Great @Joel.  That was helpful.  We would not have returned that result in a search as we were using the wrong search term.  I scanned the code and do not see any switches as to when metrics are activated vs. deactivated.  For whatever reason, we do not see newrelic capturing and sending any of the corda specific metrics.

Comment: The corda code base is using metrics.dropwizard.io library and according to their [documentation] (https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.0.0/manual/third-party.html) an additional reporter will need to be added to send metrics to new relic - https://github.com/palominolabs/metrics-new-relic.

Comment: Is that something that has to be done in the Corda codebase, or can it be done by you?

Comment: I checked with our counter parties at B3I that have more experience in the corda code base, "I think this would probably fit best as an extension to Corda, rather than something that is set up by a CorDapp. Doing it through a CorDapp would mean that other CorDapps might also try to configure their own reporters, potentially conflicting with each other. I don’t know of a standard place in Corda for defining additional code to run on Node Startup." What say you?