# Where is the best location for code that needs to run on Node, and/or Cordapp startup?

Tags: corda

I am exploring adding the [metrics-newrelic-reporter](https://metrics.dropwizard.io/4.0.0/manual/third-party.html), specific to overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51087910/jmx-metrics-and-new-relic), to enhance the corda code base.  Where is the best place to add the configuration code so that it is executed on cordapp or node startup?

Comment: I have had time this afternoon to dig into this, and found where the config files are read in and leveraged in ```net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup```.  Also found the ```NodeStartup :  AbstractNode``` Specifically, the bit of code where the Jolokia JmxReporter is registered.  I should be ok for now, and report back later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three places you might consider adding code:

- For code that runs on node startup: [`AbstractNode.kt`](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/208ac49da0caaf0dfc5ade9f8bd8a49d13f17aae/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/internal/AbstractNode.kt)
- For code that runs on CorDapp loading: [`CordappLoader.kt`](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/4ea80916675fe76f7a0e94c6feb7b608a63c3569/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/internal/cordapp/CordappLoader.kt)
- For code that runs on flow start: [`SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.kt`](https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/244167d3e906fe2e883447071ad5b1df813cf04c/node/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/node/services/statemachine/SingleThreadedStateMachineManager.kt), either in:

  - `startFlow` if the code should only affect flows started from RPC and the flow scheduler
  - `startFlowInternal` if the code should also affect initiated flows

Answer (score 1):

AbstractNode.start() is the main place to instantiate new services.